# Spring Transaction с mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-transaction

Я знаю, что Spring Transaction работает с mode = AdviceMode.PROXY по умолчанию, но у нас нет возможности открыть новую транзакцию в одном сервисе. Эта проблема решается с mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ. Но мой код работает не корректно с этими атрибутами.

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mysqlEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "mysqlTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"softserve.spring.com.repository"}
)
public class TransactionConfig {

    @Bean(name = "mysqlDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mysql.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "mysqlEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("mysqlDataSource") DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("softserve.spring.com.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("mysql")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "mysqlTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("mysqlEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory mysqlEntityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(mysqlEntityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

mysql.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_transaction?useSSL=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
mysql.datasource.username=root
mysql.datasource.password=root
mysql.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userrepository;

    @Transactional
    public void createUsers() {
        create();

        User user = new User("B", 0);
        userrepository.save(user);

        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void create() { 
       User user = new User("A", 100);
       userrepository.save(user);
}

@Transactional
public void deleteAll() {
    userrepository.deleteAll();
}

}
```

После выполнения этого кода в базе данных должен быть один пользователь. Но у меня есть два. Как правильно настроить?

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>home.spring.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-transaction</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: А вы запускаете приложение с aspectjweaver агентом или без?

Comment: без, сейчас добавлю pom.xml